# How to achieve translate animations sequentially

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi i am new to android can anyone please help me to achieve object animations one after the other sequentially, i have four set of images should repeat sequentially without the the gap between the end and start of the animation means it should look like continuously moving from right to left.

Comment: You can just set `setRepeatMode()` to `REVERSE` and set `setRepeatCount()` to `INFINITE`

Comment: Hi I have tried that, animations is repeating but there will be a gap between on first end of the animation to the next start of the animation please help me to resolve to give smooth flow without gap

Comment: Not sure if this will help but are you sure `setStartDelay()` is set to 0? and you can also try using 'CycleInterpolator' instead.

Comment: Yes am Sure setStartDelay() is set to 0 and 'CycleInterpolator' is also working same as described above

Comment: Can you post the code? That way we can help more instead of just guessing.